# M.S.Paint saveas saves gray image (single channel) as color image (three channel), why?

Tags: image

I have a gray scale image (1 channel image), and when I open it in M.S.Paint and perform "saveas" to save it to local disk, it saves it as color image (3 channel image). I would like to know why it is happening, and how can i resolve this.

e.g.

```
im1 = imread('image1_from_disk.png');
im2 = imread('image1_from_disk_saveas.png');
size(im1);
size(im2);
```

It shows answer as:
256 256 1 and
256 256 3

Comment: can you send your image here

Comment: Are you using **Matlab**? **OpenCV**? Please add the appropriate tags.